# How to get all network printers in C#

Tags: .net

I have written the following code it didnot get the Remote printers name Can any one please help me?

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM 
                                             Win32_Printer");

var results = searcher.Get();

IList<ManagementBaseObject> printers = new List<ManagementBaseObject>();
`enter code here`
foreach (var printer in results) `enter code here`{
    if ((bool)printer["Network"]) `enter code here`{`enter code here`
        printers.Add(printer);`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to find list of all **Installed Network Printers** then you can simply use the following function.

Try to run the following in by creating a Console Application.

You need to reference **System.Printing** Namespace. You need to manually add reference to its library by right-clicking on **Add References** and checking the same as shown below in the snapshot.

[image: Enter System.Printing Namespace to your local dll]

Once you are done with that then use the following code for your console application. I have added code here to **show BOTH Network and Local Printers**. You can pick your particular selection.

```
using System.Printing;
namespace GetPrinters
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new PrintServer();
            Console.WriteLine("Listing Shared Printers");
            var queues = server.GetPrintQueues(new[]
            { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Shared, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
            foreach (var item in queues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nListing Local Printers Now");
            queues = server.GetPrintQueues(new[]
            { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local });
            foreach (var item in queues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.FullName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update your code like below.

```
private void btnGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers
    var oquery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

    var mosearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;

        foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["Network"])
            {
                cmbPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I copied it from [Retrieve a List of Installed Printers on the Network Using WMI, C# and VB.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=148&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)